# PHP - Safely replace a class

Tags: php, class, extends

Suppose I have made a class:

```
class abc {
   function a() { .. }
}
```

In future, say for an updated, I made an updated version of this class, with all same functions plus some new functions and private variables:

```
class abc2 {
    function a() { .. }
}
```

Now, what I want is instead of updating my entire code to look for old class `abc` and replace it with `abc2`, is there any way that where ever, in my old code, an object of `abc` is called, it should return `abc2`. This way I won't have to update class name throughout all instances of `abc` in my code.

I know I can use `extends` keyword in class `abc2`, but I fear my private variables or function won't be accessible.

Comment: Refactor in your ide?

Comment: How about using an interface?

Comment: @Guy, Really no idea of using interfaces :(

Comment: Use interface, factory pattern, tests and read about patterns and refactoring, Luke. :^ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class abc extends abc2 {
// don't add any methods or whatever
}

class abc2 {
   function a() { .. }
}
```

This way all methods are the same for abc2 as for abc. As to the private issue, there is no easy way to solve that. Either you rewrite all of your code to fix the class or you make private methods protected. At least try to use this extend method and see if any conflicts occur, I certainly don't hope so.

A solution would have been to have namespaces where you would be able to re-code to use newnamespace\abc; instead of oldnamespace\abc; in your code. This would however also mean rewriting code.